# Batch insertion with Spring MVC and Hibernate 3

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, batch-processing, lazy-initialization

I am using Spring MVC + Hibernate and try to save bulk record using "hibernate batch procession technique" but getting below exception when I am doing `session.flush()` and `session.clear()`.

**org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session**

following is my code sample

1. DaoImpl method

   ```
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           @Override
           public String transferPsalesDataToMisSales() {  
               Session session = null;
               Transaction tx=null;
               String result="failed";         
               try {session = this.getSessionFactory().openSession();          
                   tx = session.beginTransaction();                        
                   Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(PsalesInfo.class);         
                   List<PsalesInfo> pSalesData=criteria.list();                
                   if(pSalesData.size() >0){               
                       Iterator<PsalesInfo> it=pSalesData.iterator();
                       int index=0;
                       MisSalesInfo mis=null;
                       while(it.hasNext()){
                           mis=new MisSalesInfo();
                           PsalesInfo psales=it.next();                        
                           StockistInfo stockistInfo=psales.getStockistInfo();
                           TalukaInfo talukaInfo=stockistInfo.getTalukaInfo();                     
                           IsrInfo isr=(IsrInfo) session.get(IsrInfo.class, stockistInfo.getIsrId());                      
                           //mis settters
                           mis.setMisSalesId(psales.getPsalesId());                        
                           mis.setStateName(talukaInfo.getDistrictInfo().getStateInfo().getStateName());                       
                           mis.setDistName(talukaInfo.getDistrictInfo().getDistName());                        
                           mis.setTalukaName(talukaInfo.getTalukaName());                                  
                           mis.setAsmId(talukaInfo.getAsmInfo().getAsmId());                       
                           mis.setTsoId(stockistInfo.getTsoInfo().getTsoId());                 
                           if(null!=isr){
                               mis.setIsrId(isr.getIsrId());
                               mis.setIsrName(isr.getIsrName());                           
                           }
                           mis.setUnitNo(stockistInfo.getUnitNo());                    
                           mis.setBillNo(psales.getBillNo());              
                           session.save(mis);                      
                           if(index % 50==0){
                               //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
                               session.flush();
                               session.clear();
                           }
                           index++;
                       }//end of while         
                       tx.commit();                
                       result=pSalesData.size()+" Psales are Successfully transfered to MIS Sales";                
                   }
                   else{
                       result="No Psales is available to transfer since  are already available in MIS Sales";
                   }           
               } catch (HibernateException e) {
                   tx.rollback();          
                   logger.error("error  in MasterDaoImpl transfer data:"+e);           
               }finally {
                   if (null != session)
                       session.close();
               }
               return result;
           }
   ```
2. POJOs

   ```
           @Entity
           @Table(name = "psales_info", catalog = "secondary_sales")
           public class PsalesInfo implements java.io.Serializable {   
               private static final long serialVersionUID = 5578632011679493005L;
               private Integer psalesId;
               private StockistInfo stockistInfo;
               //and some other attributes
             //getter and setters
           @Id
               @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
               @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
               @Column(name = "psales_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
               public Integer getPsalesId() {
                   return this.psalesId;
               }

               public void setPsalesId(Integer psalesId) {
                   this.psalesId = psalesId;
               }

               @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
               @JoinColumn(name = "pcode", nullable = false)
               public StockistInfo getStockistInfo() {
                   return this.stockistInfo;
               }
       //and others

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "stockist_info", catalog = "secondary_sales")
   public class StockistInfo implements java.io.Serializable {
       private String stockistId;
       private TalukaInfo talukaInfo;
   //and rest attributes
   //getters and setters
   // Property accessors
       @Id 
       @Column(name = "stockist_id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
       public String getStockistId() {
           return this.stockistId;
       }

       public void setStockistId(String stockistId) {
           this.stockistId = stockistId;
       }

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "taluka_sid", nullable = false)
       public TalukaInfo getTalukaInfo() {
           return this.talukaInfo;
       }
   ```
3. ServiceImpl

   ```
   @Service
   @Transactional
   public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionService {
       @Autowired
       private TransactionDAO transactionDAO;

   @Override
   public String transferPsalesDataToMisSales() {      
       return this.getTransactionDAO().transferPsalesDataToMisSales();
   }


   }
   ```
4. dispature-servlet.xml

   ```
   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
       <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
       <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>

       <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
               <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
               <prop key="hibernate.default_catalog">${hibernate.default_catalog}</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>                                         
           </props>
       </property>
   </bean>

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 

   <bean id="transactionManager" 
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
         p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
   ```

Need help here why it is throwing LazyInitializationException when I'm clearing the session.

But when I'm not clearing the session ie. wihtout `session.clear()` and `session.flush()` application is running properly.

but I know it may lead to `OutOfMemoryException` in case of more bulk record.

so plz tell how to deal with this situation now?

Answer (score 1):

Your dao code is flawed... Don't open new sessions yourself and don't mess aroudn with transactions yourself either. Remove the transaction stuff from your dao method and the call to `openSession` should be replaced with `getCurrentSession`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public String transferPsalesDataToMisSales() {  
    Session session = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(PsalesInfo.class);         
    List<PsalesInfo> pSalesData=criteria.list();                
    int index=0;

    for (PsalesInfo psales : pSalesData) {
        MisSalesInfo mis=new MisSalesInfo();
        StockistInfo stockistInfo=psales.getStockistInfo();
        TalukaInfo talukaInfo=stockistInfo.getTalukaInfo();                     
        IsrInfo isr=(IsrInfo) session.get(IsrInfo.class, stockistInfo.getIsrId());                      
        //mis settters
        mis.setMisSalesId(psales.getPsalesId());                        
        mis.setStateName(talukaInfo.getDistrictInfo().getStateInfo().getStateName());                       
        mis.setDistName(talukaInfo.getDistrictInfo().getDistName());                        
        mis.setTalukaName(talukaInfo.getTalukaName());                                  
        mis.setAsmId(talukaInfo.getAsmInfo().getAsmId());                       
        mis.setTsoId(stockistInfo.getTsoInfo().getTsoId());                 
        if(null!=isr){
            mis.setIsrId(isr.getIsrId());
            mis.setIsrName(isr.getIsrName());                           
        }
        mis.setUnitNo(stockistInfo.getUnitNo());                    
        mis.setBillNo(psales.getBillNo());              
        session.save(mis);                      
        if(index % 50==0){
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
        index++;
    }//end of loop         

    if (pSalesData.isEmpty() ) {
         return "No Psales is available to transfer since  are already available in MIS Sales";
    } else {
        return pSalesData.size()+" Psales are Successfully transfered to MIS Sales";                
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Deinum,thanks for your reply!!! as you said to use   getCurrentSession ..I did but that is throwing no session exception...Throughout  my application we used this.getsessionFactory.openSession() for session and closing after function ends. so current session in not available i thing..plz tel me the alternative..

Comment: Don't use `opensession`! that basically renders springs tx support useless. If there is no active session it indicates that your tx setup is wrong. Fix that instead of trying to work around it by using `opensession`.

Comment: can you give any reference that i can use follow to fix ...i have no idea why .getCureentSession() is not working....as you can see my dispature-servlet.xml i used org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager and i use @autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory  on my daoImpl

Comment: Those should be ideally in the context that contains your services. My guess is those are in the context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and not by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: i got your point now...but still have one doubt..just tell me if we use .getCurrentSession() not .openSession() then when and where to close that session ? As I know In sessionFactory we can have limited number of session at a time...so for each functions  in daoImpl class we are getting session object by .getCurrentSession but not closing ,it may lead to exception of more than session object in session factory right?  if it is managed by spring plz let me know then i will chnage my project structure whereerver i used .openSession() ,i will use .getCurrentSession()

Comment: You don't close the session nor manage transactions as Spring does that for you. That is the whole point of using declarative transaction management that you don't need to be bothered with it.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I changed all my session object getting from .openSession() to .getCurrentSession().                               But still getting the same issue. I think I got issue.If you can see pSalesData list I am getting from same session ..so when I am clearing that session that pSalesData ,I think no more available ..that is why after 50th loop iteration I am getting this issue ......is it a problem..if yes den suggest any alternative..

Comment: Unless you are doing something else that shouldn't be an issue. As stated you shouldn't be messing around with transactions and session logic yourself. The session should still be there and open